# Is this an inversion through the origin?

Tags: geometry, vectors, transformation

I have a polar vector $e$ with $|e|=1$, and I perform a transformation $T$ that maps all other polar vectors such that $e \cdot T (s) = - e \cdot s$. One such $T$ is inversion through the origin. What can $T$ be in general, given the vectors are $d$ dimensional? What other constraints would I need to ensure that the only choice of $T$ is inversion through the origin? I.e. if I have $d-1$ non-indentical vectors $e_i$ with $i=1,\cdot\cdot\cdot, d-1$ each with the condition $e_i \cdot T (s) = - e_i \cdot s$ then I think this is sufficient, but perhaps there is a weaker condition?

Does the single constraint $e \cdot T (s) = - e \cdot s$ imply that $T$ is an inversion through the origin up to permutations of vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ need not be purely an inversion through the origin. For example, suppose $x$ is perpendicular to $s$ with $|x|=1$. Let

$$
T:s\mapsto -(e\cdot s)e + (x\cdot s)x
$$

Then, for any $s$, we have 
$$
e\cdot T(s) = e\cdot\Big( -(e\cdot s)e + (x\cdot s)x\Big)=-(e\cdot s)(e\cdot e)+(x\cdot e)(e\cdot x)=-(e\cdot s) 
$$

Furthermore, we have 
$$
T(x)= 0+(x\cdot x)x=x
$$

This example tells us a bit more too. The condition you describe is getting much closer to the truth. So long as $span(e_1,....,e_n)^\perp$ is non-empty, we can repeat the construction above. So really you need to pick a basis and add a condition for everything in that basis. Effectively, this is the same as specifying that $T$ is the inversion. There won't be a condition as simple as you'd like. You'll need something global.

Let's now assume $\{e_i\}$ is some basis, and you have conditions 
$$
e_i\cdot T(s) = -e_i\cdot s
$$

for each $1\leq i\leq d$, then $T = -I$. Consider the matrix $E$ whose columns are the vectors $e_1,..,e_d$. We can write that 
$$
e_i\cdot T(e_j) = -e_i\cdot e_j
$$
for every $i$ and $j$. The claim now amounts to 
$$
E^T TE=-E^TE
$$

You can check this entry wise. On the right, the $(i,j)$ entry is $-e_i\cdot e_j$. On the left the $(i,j)$ entry is $e_j\cdot (T e_i)$. Now because $E$ is a basis, both $E$ and $E^T$ are invertible. So $T = -I$.

Comment: thanks for the reply! So if I had a set of $e_j$ that spanned the space and $e_j\cdot T(s) = - e_j \cdot s$ for all of the $e_j$ and for any $s$ in the space, would I still need to require that the matrix $T$ is orthogonal to get that $T$ is an inversion?

Comment: Edited to discuss the stronger condition on the whole basis.

Comment: one more question: does this basis have to be orthonormal for your argument to work? many thanks

Comment: My argument only used that $E$ is invertible. Note that a matrix is invertible if and only if it's columns form a basis. I did not need to assume that it was orthogonal. So it will work with any basis.

Comment: this is great, thank you!